# Flutter: How to disable onTap for a while in gesture detector?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `GestureDetector` in a custom stateless view.
when `onTap` triggered I show a snack bar that displays some info.
When the user makes multiple clicks fast it keeps displaying the snack bar forever.

[source code](https://github.com/ammaratef45/zold-flutter-client/blob/f433b04fde3d0466dfdf1c76ed8197c1fdf8c108/zold_wallet/lib/information_view/information_view.dart#L29-L36)

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {  
    Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: idText));
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar
      (content: Text('ID copied')));
  },
  child: Icon(Icons.content_copy,),
}
```

I want to disable the `onTap` for seconds before it can be clicked again.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create a `bool` flag and define a method:

```dart
bool _enabled = true; 

void _onTap () {
  // Disable GestureDetector's 'onTap' property.  
  setState(() => _enabled = false);
  
  // Enable it after 1s.
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => setState(() => _enabled = true));
  
  // Rest of your code...          
}
```

**Usage:**

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: _enabled ? _onTap: null,
  child: Icon(Icons.content_copy),
)
```

Answer (score 33):

Wrap it in an `AbsorbPointer`

```
var shouldAbsorb = true;

AbsorbPointer(
    absorbing: shouldAbsorb,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use two others methods from `GestureDetector`:

`onTapDown`: When user is pressing your widget.

`onTapUp`: When user leave the widget.

`onTap`: Is when tap down and tap up follows. If user slide his finger too much Flutter take this like a cancel tap.

`onTapCancel`: When user cancel.

```
bool pressing = false;

GestureDetector(
  // when user is pressing
  onTapDown: (details) {
    setState(() {
      pressing = true;
    });
  },
  // when user leaved
  onTapUp: (details) {
    setState(() {
      pressing = false;
    });
  },
  // when user leaved
  onTapCancel: () {
    setState(() {
      pressing = false;
    });
  }
  // the action to do when user tap
  onTap: () {
    // code...
  }
);
```

Here is the documentation: [Flutter GestureDetector Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CopsOnRoad's answer

Can be done with the Future as well

```
setState(() => _enabled = true);
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
setState(() => _enabled = false);
```