# How do I disable a onTap after a single tap

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to disable the onTap function when a single click has been made.
I declared a var _onTap;
As per adding up a bool value true still it did not got changed...Please have a look to it.
And when in the gesture detector part each and every text is clickable in the row wise order

```
                      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Ticket {
  Ticket({
    this.tickets,
  });

  List<List<List<int>>> tickets;

  factory Ticket.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ticket(
    tickets: List<List<List<int>>>.from(json["tickets"].map((x) =>
    List<List<int>>.from(
        x.map((x) => List<int>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "tickets": List<dynamic>.from(tickets.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(
        x.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
  };
}

class TicketPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TicketPageState createState() => _TicketPageState();
}

class _TicketPageState extends State<TicketPage> {
  var nos;
  Ticket ticketList;
  String apiResult;
  bool isActive = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getNumbers();
  }

  _getNumbers() async {
    var result = await http
        .post(
        'https://tickets-qzd55332wa-de.a.run.app/generateTickets?ticketsRequired=2')
        .then((result) {
      //Waits for the API response and assigns to apiResult variable
      setState(() {
        apiResult = result.body;
      });
    });
  }

  // List tick = [
  //   {
  //     'tickets': [
  //       [
  //         [11, 5, 7, 10, 28, 9, 7, 74, 59],
  //         [1, 15, 7, 10, 8, 79, 27, 74, 9],
  //         [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 9, 77, 74, 79],
  //       ],
  //       [
  //         [21, 5, 7, 80, 8, 9, 7, 74, 49],
  //         [31, 15, 7, 10, 18, 79, 7, 74, 19],
  //         [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 79, 77, 74, 29],
  //       ],
  //     ]
  //   },
  // ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    if (apiResult == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      //Get an instance of Ticket from the API assigned to apiResponse variable
      ticketList = Ticket.fromJson(json.decode(apiResult));
      print('Tickets: ${ticketList.tickets}');

      // bool isActive = true;

      return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ticketList.tickets.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  List tripleNumbersList = [];
                  List<Widget> cells = [];
                  List<Widget> rows = [];
                  //Get the lenght of the list 'tickets' of the Ticket class
                  int ticketsCount = ticketList.tickets.length;

                  //Iterates over the lists inside the 'tickets' list of the Ticket class
                  for (int i = 0; i < ticketsCount; i++) {
                    //Get the lists of lists inside the 'tickets' list
                    tripleNumbersList = ticketList.tickets[i];
                    //Iterates over each list with other 3 lists
                    for (int j = 0; j < tripleNumbersList.length; j++) {
                      //Get one of the 3 lists
                      List<int> list = tripleNumbersList[j];
                      //Iterates over the list of numbers
                      for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                        //Adds a Widget to 'cells; list for each number
                        cells.add(Center(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 45,
                              width: 35,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                color: Colors.pink
                              ),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    if (isActive) {
                                      print('Working');
                                      setState(() {
                                        isActive = false;
                                      });
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    ' ${list[k]}  ',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                              ),
                          ),
                        ));
                      }
                      //Adds the list of 'cells' in the 'rows' list
                      rows.add(Row(children: cells));
                      cells = [];
                    }
                    //Adds a empty row to make space
                    rows.add(Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                      )
                    ]));
                  }

                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      height: h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        //color: Colors.red // covers the big box
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: rows,
                      )
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please rectify the mistake made.
Here is the output[I want pretty much the same output but it is displaying 9 tickets instead of 3 tickets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgQti.jpg)

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547443/flutter-how-to-disable-ontap-for-a-while-in-gesture-detector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to disable onTap for a while in gesture detector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547443/flutter-how-to-disable-ontap-for-a-while-in-gesture-detector)

Comment: Please check with where am I going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onTap is an action being detected you can not disable that action.
What you can do is wrap the action with boolean that updates after the first tap.
for instance:

```
bool singleTap = true;
GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {
   if (singleTap) {
    // Do something here
    setState(() {
    singleTap = false; // update bool
    });
   }
 }
 child: Text("tap Here")
)
```

Comment: This is disabling the other buttons as well
Please help me.....I have attached my complete code

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me to solve my problem) I am trying to enable / disable onTap action using a button.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a variable `bool isActive = true;` in your class.

```
GestureDetector(onTap: () {
      if (isActive) {
        print('Working');
        setState(() {
          isActive = false;
        });
      }
    })
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217711/discussion-on-answer-by-evilevidenz-how-do-i-disable-a-ontap-after-a-single-tap).

Answer (score 0):

Use AbsorbPointer widget and add InkWell or Gesture detecter under it.
AbsorbPointer accepts absorbing key which helps enable or disable listen of tap.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html